# CSS: Display element with width "inline"

Tags: css

I have an icon that I would like to be able to drop into text at arbitrary points and have it "flow" with the text.

Background:

An `<img>` tag works best for this. However, I don't want to have to specify the `href` everywhere. That will present problems in the future should the icon/location change. It also depends on me knowing the path to the image which I won't always know due to URL-rewrites and different mappings to the same page, etc. I would like to do something like `<span class="icon"></span>` and have my icon as the `background-image`. Of course, this doesn't work since you can't have width on an inline element. Having it as a block (ie. `<div>`) element doesn't work (for obvious reasons) and floating it doesn't work either. `display: inline-block;` works in some browsers but not all. Using `padding:` to pad-out the correct height and width gives mixed results in different browsers. Using an `<img>` tag with a transparent image for the `href` and a background-image 
works but seems hacky.

Any thoughts on what the best way to accomplish this would be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make the `<span class="icon"></span>` absolutely positioned within your link like so:

```
<a href="">Some text <span class="icon"></span></a>
```

You can specify width/height on absolutely positioned elements, so the CSS would look something like this:

```
a {
    position: relative;
    padding-right: 30px; /* width of your icon, assuming you're placing to the right of the text */
}

a .icon {
    display: block; /* for good measure, but won't be required in all browsers */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;

    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;

    background: url(your-icon.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

By setting the `<a>`'s postion to relative, it makes it the coordinate system for the absolutely positioned `<span class="icon">`.

**Using an Image Tag for the Icon**

If you don't know where the icon will appear, you can use an `<img>` tag with a transparent .gif as its source.

```
<p>Lorem ipsum <img src="clear.gif" alt="icon" class="icon" /> dolar velarium</p>
```

Then set the real icon source using the CSS background property:

```
img.icon {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background: url(true-icon-src.png) no-repeat 0 0;

    /* Use the following if you want to adjust the image's vertical position */
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work for me as I never know where the icon could be. It could be at the end of a link or the middle of a paragraph etc etc)

Comment: In that case `<img>` tags for the icon are your best bet.  They are the most consistently rendered inline-block element.  As a hack, you could give the image a 1px transparent .gif `src` and then set the true icon image using CSS background-image.  That way, you wouldn't have the hard coded src attributes in your markup that you were worried about.

Comment: Thanks again, Pat. I mentioned that in my original question and that has been the best solution so far. I was just hoping there was a simpler, cleaner, less-hacky-feeling way (read: not as much typing for each icon inserted because I'm lazy).

Comment: Ah, my mistake and yeah, it does have a hacky feel to it.  This'll be so much easier when `display: inline-block` works in all the browsers.

Comment: Agreed. I lament ie every day.

Answer (score 0):

This may seem a little hack-ish, but you could use `background-image` with `font-size` and pad your `span` with enough non-breaking spaces to show the image.

```
<span style="background-image:url('icon.gif'); width:200px; font-size: 36pt">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
```

Granted it won't be the exact size you'll need, but with a little finessing, you could find a suitable result.

Comment: You're right. It is ugly :) I was hoping there was an elegant solution out there. But it looks like I may be choosing between this or the <img> trick.

Comment: Yeah. Actually, I upvoted Josh's answer with the `img` tag. That'll give you better control over the size of the icon.